# Tmux Banner Issues

Tags: bash, tmux, banner

Im getting frustrated...
I definitely think this shouldn't be so hard. But here I am hours later and no real solution.

All I want is to display a text banner in top pane.
The bottom pane will be a menu and execute code. The idea is so the top pane only gets written once, and bottom pane cycles through code.

Remain-on-close is not useful, as it shows pane dead on bottom of pane. Watch kinda messes it up entirely.

```
tmux new-session -d -s Villainy 'bash ~/Transfer/Banner.sh'
tmux set -g status off
tmux split-window -l 5
tmux send 'bash ~/Transfer/Menu.sh' ENTER
tmux a
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (1) It's not clear what your code does. It's not clear what it does you don't want to happen. It's not clear what it doesn't do you do want to happen. Please [edit] and clarify. (2) `tmux send` sends keys. Sending keys is not your goal. Your goal is to run something in a pane. Sending keys to run something is like using Morse code in a grocery store. The fact that the clerk understands it does not make it the best way. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1492284/432690), although I cannot tell if it will be really helpful because the question is unclear (see the previous point).